# Cloud SQL using mysqli error

Tags: php, mysqli, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to output the results of a simple query using a Google Cloud SQL with a mysqli connection. I've properly set up a Cloud SQL instance and imported a SQL database. However, when I run my app, it seems to connect to the database - no errors are triggered there - but the logs show the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Wrong SQL: SELECT * FROM students Error: No database selected in /base/data/home/apps/s~db-php-001/1.371796924944999585/main.php on line 18
```

Here's my code:

```
$conn = new mysqli(null,"root","",null,null,"/cloudsql/db-php-001:db-instance-001");

// check connection
if($conn->connect_error) {
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$sql='SELECT * FROM students';

$rs=$conn->query($sql);
if($rs === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
  $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
}
```

Obviously, I'm triggering that error, but I'm can't figure out why. There is definitely a table named students in the database.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!! Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set your database name to null. A connection is made like so:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

The mysqli constructor can take in the following parameters (in this order):

```
$mysqli = mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port, $socket);
```

In your case, you've set the parameters to be:

```
$hostname = null; //Defaults to mysqli.default_host
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = null; //Defaults to "" 
$port = null; //Defaults to mysqli.default_port
$socket = "/cloudsql/db-php-001:db-instance-001";
```

Comment: Wow, you're right - and the Google documentation for making a mysqli connection is wrong. Here's what it says in the docs:

`$sql = new mysqli(null, "<username>", "<password>", null, null, "/cloudsql/hello-php:my-cloudsql-instance");`

Note the extra "null" where the database should be. I kept wondering where the database name was supposed to be specified, but figured since it was the only db in the instance, that was sufficient. Thank you so much - you're a life saver!

P.S. You might want to edit your answer slightly to make it:
$mysqli = new mysqli(...)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you can pass null for the database name. In the query you'd need to use the fully qualified table name (`<database>.Students` in your case). Or you can use the [mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)() function to select the database to use.